# iOS - surface detection

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, augmented-reality, arkit

I'd like to detect surfaces such as walls/ceilings with real time camera view in order to paint them with desired color. Is there any other way than using opencv? It is pretty big library and I'd rather use something native to the platform like ARKit or Vision. ARKit unfortunately is very imprecise and Vision has a limited feature detection list.

Answer (score 0):

ARKit uses feature points to detect surfaces, therefore surfaces with solid colors (like most walls) cannot be detected. As off ARKit 2.0 there is no native method to detect plane walls. Your best bet is using external frameworks (like OpenCV as you stated) or asking the user to select the corners of the wall and manually placing a plane.